# Simple Question About Well-definedness of Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

> Given $X$ be a random variable,  I was confusing about the concept of $E[X]<\infty$ and $E[X]$ well-definedness. Are these two concepts means the same thing??

When we say that $E[X]$ is well-defined, we basically mean the following: Define $X^+:=\max\{X,0\}$ and $X^-:=-\min\{X,0\}$ and let 
$$
E[X] := E[X^+] - E[X^-]
$$ where $E[X^+]<\infty$ and $E[X^-]<\infty$ or only either $E[X^+]$ or $E[X^-]$ to be infinite, i.e., we are not allow to have $\infty - \infty$.

So I could say $E[X]<\infty$ implies $E[X]$ is well-defined (since $E[X^+]$ or $E[X^-]$ are finite). But not the other way around right? Since $E[X]$ can take infinite value which fails to be $E[X]<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case, where it depends on which source you use.

If your definition for $E[X] = E[X^+] - E[X^-]$ to be well-defined indeed is that at most one of $E[X^+]$ and $E[X^-]$ can be infinite, then it is possible for $E[X]$ to be both well-defined and infinite (e.g. if $E[X^+] = \infty$ and $E[X^-]<\infty$, then $E[X]=\infty$). So you are right.

But there will also be textbooks that say that $E[X]$ is well-defined, only when both of $E[X^+]$ and $E[X^-]$ are finite, and in that case, we must have $E[X]<\infty$.

Comment: That's true, I do see some textbooks force the finiteness to define E[X] which pretty bothers me...but thanks for your explanation. @HowDoIMath